# Unable to configure log4j using Grails external Properties file

Tags: grails, log4j, grails-2.0

How can I configure log4j using a Grails external properties file?

In config.groovy:

```
grails.config.locations = [  
    "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",  
    "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",  
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",  
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"  
]
```

In ${appName}-config.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, FA  
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender  
log4j.appender.FA.File=c:/logs/mylog.log  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

No output file is created and the following is output to the console:

log4j:ERROR WARNING: Exception occured configuring log4j logging: No such property: delegate for class: java.lang.String

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I notice you have:

> "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
>       "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
>       "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
>       "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"

This might lead to redundant property declaration which could lead to issues.
I would try removing the top two classpath declared files and just sticking with one properties file.
I usually separate my properties files by environment such as (DEV,TEST,PROD) you may only need a DEV but you might want to have a PROD environment someday.  Also you need to make sure your log4j config is set up properly and is easy enough to just use what Grails gives with the **create-app** command with a little tweeking.

**Config.groovy:**

```
 environments {
        development {
           appName = "application"
           logDirectory = "/where/to/keep/local/logs/"
          }
    production {
            appName = "application"
            configDir ="/path/to/prod/app/cfg/"
             //Make sure logDirectory is defined in your properties file
            grails.config.locations = ["file:${configDir}${appName}-config.properties"]
        }
    }

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    println "Log Directory: ${logDirectory}"
    def logPrefix = "applicationName"

    appenders {
        console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} - %X{userName} - %m%n')

        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: 'stacktrace',
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
            fileName: "${logDirectory}/${logPrefix}Stacktrace.log",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern:'%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %X{userName} - %m%n')
            )

        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: 'logAppender',
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
            fileName: "${logDirectory}/${logPrefix}.log",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern:'%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %X{userName} - %m%n')
        )

        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: 'DebugLog',
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
            fileName: "${logDirectory}/${logPrefix}Debug.log",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern:'%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%X{userName}] %c{2} %m%n')
        )
   }
}
```

Also on a side note I see you are keeping your properties under the **.grails** directory, I personally wouldn't do that.  If you want to keep it with-in your application you can create **application/grails-app/cfg/** directory and accessing the file would look something like this:

```
 production {
                appName = "application"
                 //Make sure logDirectory is defined in your properties file
                grails.config.locations = ["file:../cfg/${appName}-config.properties"]
            }
```

Comment: The log4j configuration is working correctly if I use ${appName}-config.groovy. However I've not managed to get it working using ${appName}-config.properties - same error. I also tried with one property file listed in grails.config.locations. I shall use the groovy config approach for the time being.

Comment: Just changing the file from .properties to .groovy worked? I have a  3rd party config file I cannot change. What shall I do?